# AWS EMR HiveQL - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: hive, hiveql, emr

I am running a HiveQL job on AWS EMR and receive the following error (below in code block).  The instance has 39 M3.2XLarge (m3.2xlarge 8vCPU   30GB Memory 2 x 80GB SSD Storage) nodes, with a total 1.1TB of memory.

The HiveQL file loads data from S3 creating a smaller main data table in ORC format.  There are quite a few intermediate tables that execute properly before the error.  The code block that errored out was a `select count(distinct ...) from <main data table>`

Is there a way to clean/clear out memory before each new statement?
Do I need to adjust the size of the heap?
What else can I provide to help give a better sense of the data and environment?

Error...

```
    Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in fetcher#1
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:381)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.InMemoryMapOutput.<init>(InMemoryMapOutput.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl.unconditionalReserve(MergeManagerImpl.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl.reserve(MergeManagerImpl.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.copyMapOutput(Fetcher.java:411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.copyFromHost(Fetcher.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.run(Fetcher.java:165)
```

Comment: Can you paste the entire log of your hive statement?

Comment: What are your defaults for  `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` and `mapreduce.map.java.opts`, also `mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb` and `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts`? You can adjust these from within your Hive script with "SET" commands, as long as you don't bump into YARN limits (e.g. `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb`)

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter This is what I found on the AWS EMR Documentation page.  `Configuration Option Default Value
mapreduce.map.java.opts -Xmx1152m
mapreduce.reduce.java.opts -Xmx2304m
mapreduce.map.memory.mb 1440
mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb 2880
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb 1440
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb 23040
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb 23040`

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju The log file is 745 lines.  Is there a point above the code I already pasted that would be more useful than the whole output?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Here is additional data I found for the specific node we are using.  `Parameter Value
YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_HEAPSIZE 2703
YARN_PROXYSERVER_HEAPSIZE 2703
YARN_NODEMANAGER_HEAPSIZE 2048
HADOOP_JOB_HISTORYSERVER_HEAPSIZE 2703
HADOOP_NAMENODE_HEAPSIZE 3276
HADOOP_DATANODE_HEAPSIZE 1064`

Comment: My 2 cents: just before the query that fails, add something like `set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=6000 ; set mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx5000m ;` and give it a try

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter That seems to have worked.  Thanks!  Wish I had a better understanding of the whole Hadoop ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

The temporary answer has been to increase the "reducer" memory allocations...

`SET mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=6000;
SET mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx5000m;`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with needing to increase memory.  Evidently the job at this point is processing a set of intermediate map outputs that require more memory than the previous config allowed for a reducer.